# Suppressing Code Analysis Application Errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, code-analysis

The Crystal libraries referenced by our winform app cause errors in Code Analysis:

> Warning   1   CA0060 : The indirectly-referenced assembly
>   'BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' could not be found.
>   This assembly is not required for analysis, however, analysis results
>   could be incomplete. This assembly was referenced by: C:\Program
>   Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework
>   4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll.

In a few different threads, SAP "*support*" has acknowledged that this is a problem on their end (http://scn.sap.com/thread/2153539), though they are quick to point out it doesn't impact their product directly, so fixing it is of low-priority. It's been assigned reference number ADAPT01629826, but it still seems up-in-the-air as to when they'll actually fix the issue on their end.

This is a **Code Analysis Application Warning** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245349.aspx), rather than a normal Code Analysis Warning.

Because of that, **Visual Studio doesn't provide the usual "Suppress Message(s)" context menu**. I'm hoping there's a way to use *GlobalSuppressions* or something similar, but could use some help...

Even if SAP is right about the bad assembly reference not having a functional impact on their product, it still bothers me. Like the original poster, **I don't want any errors/warnings from Code Analysis.**

I'm sure others have run into this -- or at least something similar. How did you handle it? **Is there a way to exclude this specific warning from Code Analysis, so it no longer shows?**

While I don't like hard-coding exclusions, it seems like a more reliable solution than waiting around for SAP to actually push out a fix.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to suppress these without wrapping fxcpcmd or overwriting the code analysis targets to intercept the output and ignore the warning.